# Compiler displays 2147344384 when I try to get the sum of any 2 numbers... Did I do anything wrong?

Tags: c

I can't seem to get any sum right. This is a test code to see if my compiler can add 2 numbers correctly, but all it gives me is 2147344384 even if I fix the value for z. (eg. z = 6 + 4 will give me 2147344384)

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x;
        int y;


        printf("enter x: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("\nenter y: ");
        scanf("%d", &y);
           int z = x + y;
        printf("\n%d", z);


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You did you addition before you get the input.  Move `int z = x + y;` to be after you get `x` and `y`.

Comment: yup @NathanOliver Nailed it

Comment: A good-practice thing to do is always give a value to your variables.

Comment: @NathanOliver I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You are doing addition before getting inputs. so move this sum syntax `int z = x + y;` to be after get x and y input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

        int main()
        {
            int x;
            int y;


            printf("enter x: ");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            printf("\nenter y: ");
            scanf("%d", &y);

            int z = x + y;
            printf("\n%d", z);

            return 0;
        }
```